# Google visualization table header not showing

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-query-language

I'm building a small website where I display user queried data, fetched from a number of different Google spreadsheets, in a few Google visualization table.

This works fine, apart from the fact that in one of the tables, the table header is empty despite the fact that the supporting spreadsheet has a descriptive header row. This only happens for one of the tables, and the only obvious difference between its supporting spreadsheet and the spreadsheets for the other tables is that it consists exclusively of text entries.

Does anybody have an idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievably stupid as it may seem, the issue can be solved by adding a dummy column to the spreadsheet with a numeric entry. I reckon there ought to be a cleaner solution, though.